# Are there any EIP to speed up block times to stay competitive with other blockchains like EOS with .5 second block times?

Tags: block-interval, eos

Doing some research on EOS and it "seems" impressive or its just hyped up marketing.

They have .5 second block times which I can see to be very beneficial for dapp development response times. Are there any plans for Ethereum to reduce block times to under 1 second to stay competitive? The 15 second blocktimes are too slow for certain types of dapps like gaming related ones, but are ok for dapps don't require the immediate feedback.

Answer (score 2):

This discussion does not happen within Ethereum Improvement Proposals, but has its own forum:

http://ethresear.ch/